# Is Visual Studio 10 expected to compile C# files that are not part of the solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Got a Visual studio 10 solution for ASP.NET web site, and VS seems to compile `*.aspx.cs` files that are in the web site folder, that used to be part of the solution but were excluded (I no longer see these files in the solution explorer). Is it expected? If not, how could I fix it? Rebuilding solution does not help.

Also, is it expected that I cannot find the binaries for *.aspx.cs files?

Comment: It will build whatever is in the `.csproj` markup. Have you checked in there?

Comment: there is no .csproj file for the website, I would not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website is a **Web site project** as opposed to a *Web application project* (see [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)) then IIS will perform the compilation at runtime for you instead of Visual Studio - in this case the .csproj file is not used to determine what is and isn't compiled.

> There is no project file (.csproj or .vbproj). All the files in a folder structure are automatically included in the site.

I'm not sure where the compiled binaries go, but I believe that it is a temporary folder somewhere, so you shouldn't necessarily expect to see those binaries in the web site folder structure.

If you want explicit control over what is compiled and when it is compiled then you may be better off converting your project to a web application project.

Comment: To see where the dlls are being built to try to put this in your index.html or something alike: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly().Location

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. It only compiles whatever is is included in the .csproj marked as 'compile' (in the file properties window).

Try to refresh the project, open the .csproj as a file text and check if those files are referenced there.

Lastly, it might be a dependent project that references those files.

If you can't find the solution, paste the exact error given by VS

For clarification, solutions files (.sln) contains project files (.csproj); .csproj files are the ones that contain references to the files to build.